# php mysql: the simplest write to database function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i am a wiz at html & css. all other coding makes my head spin.

my buddy has a business with 3 employees. he needs me to build a web app where they say if they're available to work at that moment or not. that's it. simple enough, but i just can't find what i'm looking for.

obviously i need a database. i wanna just have a big button image that says, "on" and when they click it, it either:

a. changes the database value and reloads the page showing a "off" button.

b. changes the database value and changes the button LIVE to "off."

then i can just make a admin page he can see that loads the database values of his employees at the moment.

after a few hours on google i'm even more confused than i was when i started. examples are much too complicated, out of date, or arbitrary. i learn by reverse engineering and this is a great starting point as it doesn't get any simpler than this.

do i need to learn to write it in pdo? can someone help a complete novice to learn it correctly?

Answer (score 3):

The *answer* is essentially to write the entire application from start to finish for you. That is not the purpose of Stack Overflow. We're here to debug already-written code.

The steps for you are to:

1. Get access to a web server where PHP and MySQL are both installed.
2. Using server software like Plesk or CPanel or your hosting environment's control panel, create a MySQL database.
3. Use MySQL command-line interface or PhpMyAdmin or PhpMiniAdmin or similar tool to create database tables.
4. Build the front-end application in HTML/CSS and JavaScript (if you want no page refresh)
5. Write MySQL queries to `UPDATE` each employee's status record in the table
6. Interface between front-end and back-end by processing POST form data or using JSON/AJAX calls in a server-side language (like PHP)
7. Build admin page that `SELECT` MySQL data to show employee status (again on the server with PHP or similar language)

Comment: sorry about that. was not aware of the fact this website was for debugging only.

Comment: hey no worries-- check out the book *PHP and MySQL Web Development* it will teach you everything you need to know

Answer (score 0):

You can just put a status field against each employye in the database.
1.If the status is 1,that employee is available.If status==1 put button on else put the button off.
2.Update the database when user clicks on the button.

Comment: absolutely with ya. i understand all of that, but considering i know mostly nothing, i just wanted to ask the experts what the simplest language to write it in would be. for instance, do i write it in a two step way as a web form that would contact a .php file or would it be just some pdo on the page itself?

Comment: I think if you can learn php,that would be the better option.Php is a simple server side scripting language and an open source one.